# How to save the aggregation result into another database.[Mongodb]

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm querying on **users** collection in **information** database. Then I want to run an aggregation query and save the result in **stat** database. I tried several methods but any method does not make valid result for me.

Comment: This may be reference to your question : https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-write-aggregation-result-into-a-new-collection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *mkyong.com*'s solution, first I save the result into a variable. Then using **db.getSibilingDB()** command and **insert** command I save results in another database.

```
var results = db.users.aggregation([ ... ]);
db.getSiblingDB('stat').userStats.insert(results.toArray())
```